# when I bound ajax event to dynamically generated content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

To make my question simple, I have index.php looks like this:

```
<button>A</button>
<div id="DivHolder"></div>
```

First I click button A (in **index.php**) and trigger event:

```
$.ajax({
   url:"getButtonB.php"
})
```

Then after the $.ajax is success, I got a button B (which is generated from getButtonB.php) and append to **index.php** Finally, in **index.php**, it looks like this:

```
<div id="DivHolder"><button class="pill YES">B</button></div>
```

Next, javascript code:

```
$("#DivHolder").on("click",".pill",function(){
    var thisButton=$(this);
    if(thisButton.hasClass("NO")){
        $.ajax({
              url:"doingSomethingOne.php",
              type:"POST"
        });
        thisButton.removeClass("NO");
        thisButton.addClass("YES");
    }else if(thisButton.hasClass("YES")){
         $.ajax({
              url:"doingSomethingTwo.php",
              type:"POST"
        });
        thisButton.removeClass("YES");
        thisButton.addClass("NO");
    }
});
```

That's all the code here, and what I want these codes is that when I click Button A, I got a Button B. Then I click Button B, it will do something, say registering for a camp, if i click button B again, it will de-register the camp. All the thing different is the class to the Button B. If having class **YES**, then click to **de-register**. If having class **NO**, then click to **register**.

But these things don't work, in my real project, I change the button B background-color to show the different status (YES or NO). So when i click Button B, **it's background-color is changed, but right change back to orignal.** And fire the $.ajax(), (in the above case, it fires the **url:"doingSomethingTwo.php"**). At the second click, it **DOES NOT** trigger the other $.ajax();

**The most strange thing is that:**

1. If I remove the $.ajax() from the above script, that's say I just change the class (or in my project, just change the button B background-color), then it work; Click button B, it change to red color, click again it change back to yellow again.
2. If the button B is no dynamically generated, let's say button B is hard code in **index.php**, in this case, off course i will not use the **on** to bind event, just using

   ```
   $(".pill").click(function(){
       //do something
   })
   ```

then, every thing is fine. It will both change the background color and fire $.ajax accordingly.

If anybody has solution to my problem, please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ajax requests are async, so trying to remove or add classes right after where you define your ajax request will not work as expected. What you need is a way to know if the Ajax request is complete, and if so, then add/remove the classes that you want as needed. Here is a very simple example:

```
var xhrOne = $.ajax({
  url:"doingSomethingOne.php",
  type:"POST"
});

xhrOne.done(function () {
  thisButton.removeClass("NO");
  thisButton.addClass("YES");
});
```

Comment: Does this solve your issue? If so, please make sure to mark this answer as the correct one. Otherwise describe what doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: @istos.Thank you for your quick reply. Your answer is enlighten. I did make  mistake here. I using $("#DivHolder").ajaxComplete() the load the Button B. So, maybe next time i click Button B and trigger another $.ajax(), the .ajaxComplete() will be trigger too and consequence, the  content in the #DivHolder will be changed back to original. This certainly explains why the background color will change back to   it's original status; By the way, Your solution seems doesn't work in my situation. Any way, Thanks you very much.